# Can I validate only with jQuery or do I need PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, validation

I understand the difference between the two languages, but when it comes to form validation. Is jQuery enough?

Can I validate my form in jQuery/JavaScript and then do an AJAX call to send the completed form to an email address?  Is it even possible to send form data to an email address using JavaScript?

Or is it somewhat safer to do everything in PHP?

I ask this because using PHP is what I'm used to, however, I've recently started working with more advanced JavaScript and jQuery.

Comment: When it comes to form validation you are trying to compare apples to oranges here...

Comment: I kinda figured I was.  So should I just focus on PHP form validation and let the Javascript do the 'pretty' stuff?

Comment: Most of the answers here cover it in depth, but the jquery stuff can handle the quick and dirty, "Please fill in this form input" type stuff and the PHP should handle the actual formatting/making sure no one is trying to inject malicious code, etc.

Comment: @Robert, I took the liberty to adapt your question to fit the rules and more in sync with the content of all the answers. So I tried to focus the topic on Usability and Security issues.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you should do both of these validations
- jQuery for user friendly response to what the user is missing or entered wrong
- asap feedback from the client side.

you can't trust the client, so you always have to do server-side data checks
to make sure everything is correctly entered.

It is best to pass the data over and check it again on the server-side then complete your action (email, database inserts, outputs)

Answer (score 5):

You can make a more user friendly UI in JQuery. However, you should also do the validations in PHP (server-side) because if you do not someone could bypass the validations by turning off JavaScript.  There are also other ways to get around this, but as a general rule never trust a client to do validation.

In other words client-side validation (JQuery/JavaScript) cannot replace server-side validations.  JQuery is used more for user-experience.

Since you are worried about AJAX here is a code example:

**PHP**

```
//if there is an error:

header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
die(json_encode(array('message' => 'ERROR', 'code' => 1337)));

//if there is not an error:
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array("message"=>"All good here!"));
```

**JQuery**

```
//this is on submit, but you could do other events
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(e)
    {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "path/to/your.php",
        data: $('form').serialize(),
    success: function(data)
    {
            alert(data.message);
        },
        error:  function(xhr, status, error) {
          var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
          alert(err.Message);
        },
    dataType: "json"});
    }});
});
```

**Note:** I did not test the code above, but it may give you an idea of what to do.

Comment: So just do the pretty stuff like hover boxes when they don't enter a field, and just echo the php into the box through html?

Comment: That is a good way to do it.  You will also want to make sure that you can handle the case when the user has JavaScript turned off.  You can use AJAX or can rewrite the validations in JavaScript, but AJAX is they way I would go.

Comment: I was kinda afraid you'd mention using AJAX, I'm not very good with it.  I mean, I can get data from other pages, but when it comes to anything other than that, I'm useless.

Comment: JQuery has a very nice [AJAX function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and PHP a nice function [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).  AJAX is not as scary as it seems.  I use to be scared of it, but it is not that hard.

Comment: I'll have to look more into AJAX.  Thanks very much for your help

Comment: I added a little bit of code in hopes that it may be useful.

Comment: It is, somewhat useful.  I think I understand the majority of it.  I'm gonna start studying AJAX more so I can better understand it.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 4):

Regardless of if you decide to do any client-side validation, you'll *always* want to do server-side (PHP) validation as well because you should never *ever* trust user supplied input.

As for including jQuery/JavaScript validation as well: that's more of a stylistic or user experience question.  If want your users to have instant feedback for certain types of errors (such as missing or invalid data) then you should absolutely include some client-side validation.

Answer (score 3):

It's best if you use both: Use jQuery to test the input while the user is filling out the form or when the user presses the submit-button. That's enough in most cases, but since the user could have JavaScript turned off in their browser, you should check the sent in data with PHP as well. This is especially important if the data can mess something up on your side, for example if the data is saved into a database or something, then SQL injections could potentially make a huge mess and put your security at risk...

If you check the data with PHP, then the first jQuery part isn't absolutely necessary, but it's nice if the user gets a feedback about whether they filled the form out correctly without having to reload the page first...

And no, I don't think it's possible to send the form data to an email address using *only* JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery/JavaScript are client side scripting languages, it is very easy to bypass you should use combination of both client side and server side validation for reliable inputs. In the we need SMTP server in order to send an email that will be our server side so you have to use PHP for email your form information to an desired email destination.

I hope it's enough for your understanding :)

Answer (score 1):

It is vital that you let the server do any validation as, at the end of the day, IT is the mechanism that communicates with your database, file storage area, email process and executing any commands - I.e. anything of any consequence!

JavaScript validation is quick and useful but, as others have said, it's easily bypassed by simply turning it off! Or what if your visitor uses a browser that doesn't have JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

well.. Starting, aren't languages ​​that can opt for one or the other.

Javascript / jquery is a client-side language and PHP is a server-side language. What is this? Javascript runs on the client browser, is subject to its limitations and can be changed easily by the end user and have behaviors we did not want. Have PHP runs on the server side, where the user has no control. It is safer and, by rule, one should not ignore the PHP (or other server-side language) to validate forms. Thus, we are sure that our code does not have security flaws.

However, it is very good to use both ... jquery / JS allow you to check in real time, saving the user from submitting the form and then receive an error message ... In JS, it saves this work. And if the user "breaks" that protection hardly pass the validation server-side.

In short, PHP always ... To enhance the experience (and highly recommend), also use JS :)