# Check $_POST data with jquery before submitting the form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have a form that sends the store the `First Name` of the user in a database. I was checking the information send by the user using `regex` in php.
To make my project more interactive, I decided to validate the information `jQuery` before sending it to PHP.

My Project looks like this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<body>
    <form >
        <div>
            <label>First Name</label>
            <input name="firstname" type="text">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        
        $("form").submit(function (e) {
            
            var firstname = $(this).find('input[name="firstname"]').val();

            var regex = /^[A-Za-z0-9 \-']+$/;//Only numbers, Letters, dashes, apostrophes and spaces are accepted
            if(regex.test(firstname)){
                alert('Valid Name.');
            }else{
                alert('Invalid Name.');
                e.PreventDefault();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now I have 2 questions:

1. Is it really need to check the `First Name` in PHP again before storing the data in the database ? (To improve security)
2. How can I submit the form right after the `alert('Valid Name.');` ?

Thanks for providing your help.

Comment: use `return true` after the alert to submit the form. I would also check first name again

Comment: Please note because this is very important: Client side validation is for user convenience only and should never be relied on to ensure that server side data is valid!  You can bypass all validation by simply turning off javascript or using a commandline tool like curl to submit to your server.  If you only have client side validation, then you basically don't have validation.

Comment: 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23922284/can-i-validate-only-with-jquery-or-do-i-need-php

Comment: add action in your from to submit. In your script return true.

Comment: form will be get submitted because you're checking the validation after submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all have in mind that the validation of users input is implementing at the server side of an application only!!! You can not validate input data at client side with JS because it can be passed very easy(either by disabling javascript or by using tools like Curl).

However you can increase user experience like validate an input before submitting the form or inform the user that forgot to fill in an input.

To inform the user about a not fill in input you can just use the new html 5 attribute `required` like above

```
Username: <input type="text" name="usrname" required>
```

the `required` attribute will not let the user submit the form unless he had filled the associated input.

Also you can use the `maxlength` attribute to address a use case like "A password must have X max letters.

```
Password: <input type="password" name="pass" maxlength="8" size="8"><br>
```

**How to validate input at server side**

There are many techniques for this and you can find all of them here at Stackoverflow. Ι will refer the top voted post [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) which answer exactly your question.

Just two bullets that compact the above post that i suggest you read otherwise

- Always escape your data
- Use mysqli instead of mysql

**How can I submit the form right after the alert('Valid Name.'); ?**

this is very easy just use this code

```
    <form action="action_page.php" method="post">
    <div>
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input name="firstname" type="text">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

the above code will "send" user's input for process at action_page.php using `POST` method, where you can read using `$_POST` supergloba table like `$firstname = $_POST['fistsname']` etc.

Answer (score 0):

TRY This

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.js" ></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <body>
        <form >
            <div>
                <label>First Name</label>
                <input name="firstname" id="first_name" type="text">
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit">
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>

    <script>
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("firstName",function(value,element,param)
    {
  if(this.optional(element))
    {//This is not a 'required' element and the input is empty
      return true;
    }

  if(/^[A-Za-z0-9 \-']+$/.test(value))
    {
      return true;
    }

    return false;

},"Please enter a valid First Name");

$(function()
{
    $('#myform').validate(
      {
      rules:
        { 
          first_name:{ required:true, firstName:true }
        }
      });

});
    </script>
```

Comment: Kindly comment your answer, because I do not see the difference between your code and mine

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should ALWAYS validate server side for form submission, especially if you are passing those value along to a DB - SQL injection, the struggle is real.

As for the form submission flow you can...

```
return true
```

... after the valid name alert and the form to submit as it normally would.

Since you already have bound to that submit event, It would be even better for the user if you submitted the form via ajax, and providing feedback if the server validation fails.  Thus the user never leaves the page and you are able to handle both client and server validation.

Take a look at ParsleyJS - http://parsleyjs.org/ - w00t!