# Stop form submission on empty input field

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want when my input field of a form is empty it shows me alert and stops form submission. Now problem with my code is that it only shows alert but does not stop form submission . Here my html input field and script:

```js
function required() {
  var empt = document.forms["me_validate"]["insert_vender_emails"].value;
  if (empt == "") {
    alert("Please fill out the vendor email field");

  }

}
```

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="validate-me" method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="phpcode_class.php" role="form" name="me_validate" onsubmit="return required()">
  <textarea type="text" id="tags" name="insert_vender_emails" class="form-control" placeholder="">
    <?php if($n_vendors!='' ) { echo $n_vendors; } else { echo $rfq[ 'vender_emails']; } ?>
  </textarea>
</form>
```

I really got stuck in this. Please help me to get rid out of this...thanks in advance

Comment: simple thing is that use html5 required.

Comment: but i want alert box

Comment: Than js is must as u have done.

Comment: where is your submit button

Answer (score 0):

```
<html><head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function submit_form() {
            if (conditions) {
                document.forms['myform'].submit();
            }
            else {
               alert("Validation Failed;");
            }
        }

    </script>
</head><body>

    …

    <input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="submit_form();"/>

</body></html>
```

Comment: Please describe what you changed, and why. Quality answers not only show, but also explain the solution.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
        <script>
          function required()  
          {  
            var empt = document.forms["me_validate"]  ["insert_vender_emails"].value;  
            if (empt == "")  
            {  
              alert("Please fill out the vendor email field");  
               return false;
               }  

           }  

        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please put return false; after alert message. Please check below code.

```
<script>
    function required()  
    {  
        var empt = document.forms["me_validate"]["insert_vender_emails"].value;  
        if (empt == "")  
        {  
            alert("Please fill out the vendor email field");  
            return false;

        }  

    }  
</script>
```

Comment: Please use $.trim() function as well it will remove unnecessary spaces as well from the textbox. for e.g. $.trim(empt).

Comment: And one more thing can you please get the textarea value using.
var empt =  $("#tags").val(); 
or if no jquery added then use following code.
var empt = document.getElementById("tags").value;

Answer (score 0):

When you submit the form it will reload all page again.

Use **`return false`** to overcome this situation.

```
<script>
 function required()  
 {  
   var empt = document.forms["me_validate"]["insert_vender_emails"].value;  
   if (empt == "")  
   {  
      alert("Please fill out the vendor email field");
      return false;
   }  
 } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you are not selecting element properly,

```
function required()  
{  
 var empt = document.getElementById("tags").value;  
 if (empt == "")
 {  
    alert("Please fill out the vendor email field");
    return false;
 }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After alert pop up message,try to return some thing to the form.

```
 <script>
     function required()  
      {  
        var empt = document.forms["me_validate"]["insert_vender_emails"].value;  
        if (empt == "")  
         {  
           alert("Please fill out the vendor email field");  
            return false;
         }  
          return (true);

      }  

 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the new HTML5 `required` attribute

```
<textarea type="text" id="tags" name="insert_vender_emails" class="form-control" placeholder="" required></textarea>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp

Keep in mind that, with this way you cannot validate input data. Validation exist only at server-side of an appication. have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38305238/check-post-data-with-jquery-before-submitting-the-form/38307171#38307171) post too

Answer (score 0):

call `required` `function` **`onsubmit()`** and return false if `textarea` is empty

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="validate-me" method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="phpcode_class.php" role="form"  name="me_validate" onsubmit="return required()">
    <textarea type="text" id="tags" name="insert_vender_emails" class="form-control" placeholder="" ><?php if($n_vendors!='') { echo $n_vendors; } else { echo $rfq['vender_emails']; } ?></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" onsubmit="required()">
    </form>

    <script>
    function required()  
    {  
    var empt = document.forms["me_validate"]["insert_vender_emails"].value;  
    if (empt == "")  
    {  
    alert("Please fill out the vendor email field");  
    return false;
    }

    }  

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 "required" validation as :

```
<textarea type="text" id="tags" name="insert_vender_emails" class="form-control" placeholder="" required>
       <?php if($n_vendors!='' ) { echo $n_vendors; } else { echo $rfq[ 'vender_emails']; } ?>
   </textarea>
```

OR

Simply write "return false;" after alert message in your required function like :

```
   function required() {


 var empt = document.forms["me_validate"]["insert_vender_emails"].value;


if (empt == "") {
alert("Please fill out the vendor email field");
return false;


}

}
```